# Outlook 2003 crashes when trying to access Using Colors or Automatic Formatting

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

I'm trying to shrink the font used to display the messages in an outlook 2003 inbox.
To get there I need to get to "Automatic Formatting" but every time I try outlook crashes.
If there is another way to accomplish this same goal I would be willing to try.

Additional info:
Win XP
Email on a server